# excel - if cell is not blank, then do IF statement

Tags: excel

I have this simple statement in `excel`. I compare two dates. If the date 2 is greater than or equal to date 1, then I show **1**. If not, then I show **0**.

However, I would like to apply this function **only** when the cells contains text:

```
IF(NOT(ISBLANK((Q2<=R2;"1";"0")))
```

That gives me an error - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which cell should not be blank? Q2? R2? Both?

Comment: Both cells should contain data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your formula is wrong. You probably meant something like:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Q2));NOT(ISBLANK(R2)));IF(Q2<=R2;"1";"0");"")
```

Another equivalent:

```
=IF(NOT(OR(ISBLANK(Q2);ISBLANK(R2)));IF(Q2<=R2;"1";"0");"")
```

Or even shorter:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Q2);ISBLANK(R2));"";IF(Q2<=R2;"1";"0"))
```

**OR EVEN SHORTER:**

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Q2);ISBLANK(R2));"";--(Q2<=R2))
```

Comment: Since the output is either 0 or 1, this could also be: `=(Q2<>"")*(R2<>"")*(Q2<=R2)` This will evaluate each statement in parantheses as either TRUE or FALSE which is equivalent to either 0 or 1. Then multiply them together. All three statements must be true to get a 1.

Comment: Well, yes but... I just don't feel like multiplying boolean expressions... `*` belongs to arithmetic. I think.

Comment: It's a computer; Everything is arithmetic. I like your answers though, they are probably better suited to OPs comfort level and are easier to change. If in the future OP wanted to have it output "Yes" or "No" instead of 1 or 0, then the nested IFs are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AND statement in your formula

=IF(AND(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Q2));TRUE;FALSE);Q2<=R2);"1";"0")

And if both conditions are met, return 1.

You could also add more conditions in your AND statement.

Comment: This could be shortened to `=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Q2));Q2<=R2);"1";"0")`. `=IF(boolean;TRUE;FALSE)` is equivalent to `=boolean`. Plus your variant will **always** return a value, even if one or both of the cells are empty.